# How to direct to another component page angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have trouble to direct an angular page to another component which i created. It should be directed to 'belize-local-time-component' when I click "take me back". But for right now, when I click "take me back", it directed to 'belize-local-time-component'page, but it did not stay, instead of coming back to the current page. Please help!! Thank you.

welcome-component.component.html

```
<p>
  This is what I'm all about. <a href="" (click)="sendMeHome()"><strong>Take me back</strong></a>.
</p>
```

welcome-component.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-welcome-component',
  templateUrl: './welcome-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./welcome-component.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => console.log(res.id));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendMeHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['./belize-local-time-component']);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponentComponent } from './welcome-component/welcome-component.component';
import { BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent } from './belize-local-time-component/belize-local-time-component.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponentComponent,
    BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { WelcomeComponentComponent} from './welcome-component/welcome-component.component';
import { BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent } from './belize-local-time-component/belize-local-time-component.component';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WelcomeComponentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'belize-local-time-component',
    component: BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please add your  BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent code?

Comment: I have not write anything on BelizeLocalTimeComponentComponent  yet.  ;/.  @Bahman

Comment: Append pathMatch: full property to your default route definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your anchor tag in Welcome component. You should remove href="" or use a button instead. Please check this sample that I have created for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yarabq

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of the paths in your routes.